# Do not know where's the error

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run my program this error comes out for the following sql statement

```
SqlCommand Item1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE ItemTable (ItemProductPlu = '" +        ProductPlu1 + "',ItemProductQty ='" + ProductQty1 + "' ,Fufilled'" + Fufilled + " ')' WHERE ItemId = Max(ItemId)", conn);
```

Error :

> SqlException was unhandled by user code
>
> Incorrect syntax near '='.
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' WHERE ItemId = Max(ItemId)'.

Comment: Shouldn't there be `Fufilled =` in there somewhere?

Comment: Yes, can't believe I did not notice that obvious error.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection. Using parametrized queries also often solves issues with missing or erroneous quotes, date as string formatting and more

Comment: I am aware of this inject function that sql has. However is it really necessary and worth the extra coding? The possibility of the user entering a sql statement seems almost 0. @marc_s

Comment: SQL Injection is the **#1 vulnerability** out there - leading to **massive security breaches** everywhere. ***YES*** it ***IS*** worth the extra coding!

Comment: Noted. Will implement it when my project is properly functioning. Would you by any chance know how to solve this error? I feel like im not using the Max() function properly. @marc_s

Comment: Please read the [documentation on `UPDATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) instead of trying to come up with the syntax yourself. I'm not seeing `SET` keyword in your statement...

Comment: Also, `MAX(ItemId)` from what exactly? That part won't work either. Best change the `WHERE`-clause to `WHERE ItemId=(SELECT MAX(ItemId) FROM ItemTable)`

Comment: Thank you @TT. I changed the Where clause and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working code is this:

```
SqlCommand Item1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE  ItemTable SET ItemProductPlu = '" + ProductPlu1 + "',ItemProductQty ='" + ProductQty1 + "' ,Fufilled = '" + Fufilled + "' WHERE ItemID=(SELECT MAX(ItemID) FROM ItemTable) ", conn);
```

The following changes were made:

> Applied '=' after "Fufilled".
>   Removed " ' " before "WHERE"
>   Added 'SET' before ItemProductPlu
>   Took away the brackets () containing
>   `ItemProductPlu = '" + ProductPlu1 + "',ItemProductQty ='" + ProductQty1 + "' ,Fufilled'" + Fufilled + " '`
>   Added this `ItemId =(SELECT MAX(ItemId) FROM ItemTable)` after WHERE

This answer was achieved with the collective help of NP0410 , marc_s ,  John3136 , rajeshpanchal and TT. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand Item1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE ItemTable (ItemProductPlu = '" +        ProductPlu1 + "',ItemProductQty ='" + ProductQty1 + "' ,Fufilled = '" + Fufilled + " ') WHERE ItemId = Max(ItemId)", conn);
```

Try this, I have made following changes:

1. Applied '=' after "Fufilled".
2. Removed "'" before  "WHERE"

Comment: Also apply keyword "SET" after "UPDATE ItemTable "

Comment: `SqlCommand Item1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE  ItemTable SET (ItemProductPlu = '" + ProductPlu1 + "',ItemProductQty ='" + ProductQty1 + "' ,Fufilled = '" + Fufilled + " ') WHERE ItemId = Max(ItemId)", conn);` this is what the new code looks like but 'incorrect systax near '(' now comes up